# Invisible account and Pull Request at Github

Tags: github

Have you ever met the issue, when you created new account at Github, can collaborate on projects, by creating Pull Requests. But **no one** besides you can see your profile or your pull request.
Here's the account having such problem https://github.com/9helgas9
It definitely exists.
And the pull request exists as well - https://github.com/IlyaOrlov/PythonCourse2.0_May23/pull/45 (see the screenshot attached -
[pull request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MATE.jpg))

If I try to create new pull request with the same number - 45, Github will say that it already exists. So Github definitely detects the pull request.

Also I double checked Contribution & Activity section in the Profile - it doesn't have any private marks.

If somebody has any idea how to solve this, please, help.